# pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'humps'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pipenv

I am creating a .exe from my python program on Windows with pyinstaller. When executing the .exe-File I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'humps'`.

My Pipfile contains `[packages] pyhumps ="~=3.0"` so it is installed in the virtual env.
The pyinstaller command is executed in the virtual env with: `pipenv run pyinstaller --paths external --hidden-import pyhumps --clean src/main.py`

In the log of the pyinstaller I see the following error:

```
4507 INFO: Analyzing D:\projects\automation\src\main.py
4601 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pyhumps'
4601 ERROR: Hidden import 'pyhumps' not found
4601 INFO: Processing module hooks...
```

Edit I created a MRE:

1. Create python file `main.py`:

```py
from humps import camelize

in_ = input("String: ")
print(camelize(in_))
```

2. In the same directory create venv and compile: `pipenv --python 3 && pipenv install pyhumps && pipenv run pyinstaller --hidden-import pyhumps main.py`
3. Executing `.\dist\main\main.exe` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'humps'`

Comment: Interesting module name!

Comment: Solved. Had to install pyinstaller in the pipenv venv with `pipenv install pyinstaller`.